# Vuejs component disappears on page load

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I'm experiencing a weird issue in vue. I've set up a component to view details of an item, this component accepts props and renders on first load but when i reload the page, the entire component disappears including the Root.

I've tried to name router-view but it doesn't work.

MainApp.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <transition name="fade">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
      transition: opacity .5s
    }
    .fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
      opacity: 0
    }
</style>

<script>

    export default{

    }
</script>
```

Routes.js

```
import ViewProduct from './store/View.vue'

const routes = [
    {
      name: 'viewProduct',
      path: 'product/:id/view/:slug',
      component: ViewProduct,
      props: true
    }
];

export default routes;
```

Main.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
import routes from './routes';

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes});
import MainApp from './MainApp'
import store from './store/store/index'

new Vue({
  el: '#storeapp',
  render: h => h(MainApp),
  router,
  store: store,
});
```

I have another router-view container which works fine but this one does not.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on codepen?

Comment: This is pretty much it https://codepen.io/skyrpex/pen/mwmJRe?editors=1010 without vuex

Comment: @LDUBBS Cannot be reproduced. It always shows some message on the screen. And what is the DevTools' reload button? There is only one reload button...

Comment: I fixed it, my bad, i wasn't catching all routes properly, problem was in routes/web.php in laravel.